# Check database field in entity on Symfony platform

Tags: symfony

When my controller request the new account the entity generates automatically it's customer ID. This is done with the following code:

```
/**
 * Set custId
 *
 * @param integer $custId
 * @return Account
 */
private function setCustId()
{
    $this->custId = rand(1000, 9999);

    return $this;
}
```

Only in this entity I want to check if there is already a customer in the database. So adding the following code and repeating this until a free ID if found. But already tried to access the database with the code below, but i'm getting an php error. Anyone some idee?

```
 $account = $this->getDoctrine()
            ->getRepository('MyBundle:Account')
            ->findOneBy(array('custId' => $this->custId));
```

Comment: Just an idea. You should check the random number before assign it to the entity.

Comment: When a new account is generated the __construct function inits the setCustId function. This way the CustId goes fully automatic.

Answer (score 0):

1. You can use **[uniqid](http://php.net/manual/en/function.uniqid.php)** to generate a unique ID.
2. Second way, Doctrine level:

   @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="UUID")

More about [Identifier Generation Strategies](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/basic-mapping.html#identifier-generation-strategies)

**UPDATE**

You can create [Event Listener](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/event_listeners_subscribers.html) and use **PrePersist** event.
Inside this event you can check any rules for your entity.

Comment: My id is not fully unique, but to simplify the question I made it unique in the question. I would like to know if it is possibly to get a value from the database in the entity to check if it is already used?